# Отправка Post запроса для CRM

Tags: php, post

Для ведения и учета заказов используется *CRM* система.

Нужно, чтобы заявки и отзывы, которые отправляются с сайта, не просто приходили на почту, но еще и отображались в *CRM*, то есть организовать их передачу на автомате по *api*.

Как осуществить *Post-запрос* из данной формы, используя данный *api*?

### api

1) Для добавления заказа нужно послать POST запрос на `http://www.superchistka.dev.avenuemedia.ru/api/order/` параметры запроса:

- name - Имя
- phone - Телефон
- email - Электронная почта
- comment - Дополнительная информация
- services - массив кодов выбранных услуг:

  - furniture - химчистка мягкой мебели
  - mattress - химчистка матрасов
  - carpet - химчистка ковров на дому
  - factory-carpet-cleaning - химчистка ковров на фабрике
  - cleaning - уборка помещений
- other - иное

Значения полей "Удобное время для связи с Вами" и "Срочно" нужно передавать в параметре comment отделяя от дополнительной информации новой строкой (у нас в админке для этих параметров нет отдельных полей).

**Пример передачи параметров:**

```
 email=test@test.ru&name=test&phone=123456&comment=comment&services[0]=mattress&services[1]=cleaning&services[2]=factory-carpet-cleaning
```

2) Для добавления отзыва нужно послать POST запрос на `http://www.superchistka.dev.avenuemedia.ru/api/review` параметры запроса:

- name - Имя
- email - Электронная почта
- comment - Отзыв
- serviceDate - Дата оказания услуги (в формате ДД-ММ-ГГГГ)

**Пример передачи параметров**

```
email=test@test.ru&name=test&comment=comment&serviceDate=01-02-2015
```

Оба метода в случае успеха возвращают json:
{"success":true}

В случае ошибки метод возвращает json c описанием ошибки в поле error.
Например:

> {"error":"empty parameter: name"}

### Сам код для изменения

```
<?php
//order.php @26aug2010 #104@rv71
################################################################################ Определения
    $svc=array("химчистка мягкой мебели", "химчистка матрасов", "химчистка ковров на дому","химчистка ковров на фабрике","уборка помещений","иное");//Список услуг. Можно пополнять в том же формате
    $url_ok="/order_ok.shtml";//Если всё верно и заказ отправлен
    $url_bad="/order_bad.php";//Если где-то косяк
    $mailto="order@test.ru";//Кому письмо
    $mailfrom="order@test.ru";//От кого письмо
    $subject="Новый заказ на сайте";//Тема письма

################################################################################ Основной скрипт
function checked($name,$value,$subj){$value=intval($value);if($value>0){$value=" checked";}else{$value="";}return str_replace(chr(0x7B)."checked_".$name.chr(0x7D),$value,$subj);}
function value($name,$value,$subj){$value=str_replace("'","",str_replace('"',"",trim($value)));if(strlen($value)>0){$value=" value='".$value."'";}else{$value="";}return str_replace(chr(0x7B)."value_".$name.chr(0x7D),$value,$subj);}
session_start();$lst=$mrs=$hur=$urgent="";$err=$mrk=0;
if(count($_POST)>0){
    unset($_SESSION['_post']);
    $_SESSION['_post']=array();
    $_SESSION['_post']=$_POST;
    unset($_SESSION['_post']['uspam']);
    $uname=trim($_POST['uname']);//Req:Name
    $umail=trim($_POST['umail']);//Req:Email
    $uphone=trim($_POST['uphone']);//Nrm:Email
    $urgent=intval(trim($_POST['urgent']));//Nrm:Urgent
    $udesc=trim($_POST['udesc']);//Nrm:Description
    $uspam=trim($_POST['uspam']);//Req:Urgent
    if(($uname=='')or($uname==' ')){$err++;}
    //if(($umail=='')or($umail==' ')or(!substr_count($umail,"@")==1)){$err++;}
    foreach($svc as $k=>$sc){//Создаём список услуг из массива выше и сверяем его
        if(intval($_POST['svc_'.($k+1)])==1){
            $mrs.="- ".$sc."<br />\n";$mrk++;
        }
    }
    if($mrk==0){$err++;}
    if($uphone==""){$uphone="[не указан]";}
    if(md5($uspam)==md5($_SESSION['captcha_keystring'])){ }else{$err++;}
    unset($_SESSION['captcha_keystring']);//Убиваем поток, чтобы нельзя было отправить форму с одним и тем же кодом дважды (спамерам привет)
    if($err>0){
        $url=$url_bad;
    }else{
        if($urgent==1){$hur=" с пометкой <b><u>СРОЧНО</u></b>";$urgent="СРОЧНО: ";}else{$hur=$urgent="";}
        require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/img/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');
        $subj=$urgent.$subject." ".str_replace("www.","",$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
        $head="<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN\">\n".
        "<html>\n<head>\n<meta http-equiv=\"Content-type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\">\n".
        "<title>".$subj."</title>\n</head>\n";
        $msg="<body bgcolor='#ffffff' style='font:normal 12px Tahoma;color:#000;'>\n".
        "Здравствуйте,<br />\n".date("d.m.Y в H:i:s")." был получен новый заказ".$hur."<br />\n<br />\n".
        "<b>Заказчик</b>: ".$uname."<br />\n".
        "<b>Электронная почта</b>: ".$umail."<br />\n".
        "<b>Телефон</b>: ".$uphone."<br />\n".
        "<b>Требуемые услуги</b>:<br />\n".$mrs."<br />\n".
        "<b>Дополнительная информация</b>:<br />\n".$udesc."<br />\n".
        "<br />\n____________________________________________<br />\n".
        "С уважением, система получения заказов</body>\n</html>";
        try{
            $mail= new PHPMailer(true);
            $mail->CharSet='utf-8';
            $mail->SetFrom($mailfrom);
            $mail->AddReplyTo($mailfrom);
            $mail->Subject=$subj;
            $mail->AltBody=strip_tags($msg);
            $mail->MsgHTML($head.$msg);
            $mail->AddAddress($mailto);
            $mail->Send();
            $url=$url_ok;
            unset($_SESSION['_post']);//CleanIT
            session_destroy();//CleanIT
        } catch (phpmailerException $e) {
            $url=$url_bad;//Suspend
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $url=$url_bad;//Suspend
        }
    }
    header("Location: ".$url);exit("FORCE-REDIR");
}else{
    foreach($svc as $k=>$sc){//Создаём список услуг из массива выше и делаем его "галочками"
        $lst.=checked("svc_".($k+1),$_SESSION['_post']['svc_'.($k+1)],'<label for="svc'.($k+1).'d"><input name="svc_'.($k+1).'" type="checkbox" value="1" id="svc'.($k+1).'d"{checked_svc_'.($k+1).'}><span>'.$sc.'</span></label>'."<br />\r\n");
    }
    //$o=file_get_contents("order_template.shtml");//Путь и имя до файла-шаблона
    ob_start();
    include("order_template.shtml");
    $o = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
        $o=
        str_replace("{svc_list}",$lst,
        value("uname",$_SESSION['_post']['uname'],
        value("umail",$_SESSION['_post']['umail'],
        value("uphone",$_SESSION['_post']['uphone'],
        checked("urgent",$_SESSION['_post']['urgent'],
        str_replace("{udesc}",$_SESSION['_post']['udesc'],
        str_replace("{uri}",$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],$o
        )))))));//Подменяем понятия О_o
    exit($o);//Отдаём посетителю страницу
}
?>
```

Comment: как я понимаю, вы привели выдержку из документации к *api*. а в чём именно у вас трудности, к сожалению, непонятно.

Comment: Как осуществить Post запрос из данной формы, используя данный  api?

Comment: внёс ваш комментарий в текст вопроса.

Answer (score 2):

Из php – [cURL](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.curl.php)'ом: вы в скрипте получили все данные, формируйте из них post-запрос:

```
$params = array(
    'email' => 'test@test.ru',
    'name'  => 'test',
    'comment'   => 'trololo',
    'serviceDate'   => '01-02-2015',    
);

$ch = curl_init('http://www.superchistka.dev.avenuemedia.ru/api/review');
curl_setopt_array( $ch, array(
    CURLOPT_HEADER  => FALSE,
    CURLOPT_POST    => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 10,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS  => $params,

    CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH => CURLAUTH_ANY,
    CURLOPT_USERPWD => "ваш_логин:ваш_пароль",
));
$response = curl_exec( $ch);

$data = json_decode($response);
if( !$data) {
    // ответ не JSON
} else if( isset($data->success)  &&  $data->success) {
    // Ура, все получилось
} else if( isset($data->error) {
    // ошибка параметров
    echo 'Ошибка: ' . $data->error;
} else {
    // вообще какая-то непредусмотренная фигня происходит
}
```

**Upd.** ------------

Как проверить отмеченные чекбоксы. Напр. если отмечен чекбокс `<input type="checkbox" name="svc_2" value="1">`, то в массиве `$_POST` будет присутствовать значение `$_POST['svc_2'] = 1`. Проверяйте напр. так:

```
if( isset( $_POST['svc_2'])) ...чекбокс отмечен
```

Для вашей задачи еще нужно установить соответствие между русскими и английскими названиями услуг, т.к. api требует их английские имена.

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь!

Comment: пытаюсь разобраться, но пока тщетно - запрос не отправляется, выдает  _ответ не JSON_, не могу понять, где именно нужно вставить этот скрипт

Comment: посмотрите, что там в `$response` получается.

Comment: выдает 401 ошибку - Authorization Required. Насколько известно, там двух-факторная авторизация

Comment: Добавил в ответ опции для авторизации.

Comment: Спасибо за ответы! делал тоже самое, но там авторизоваться требуется дважды. То есть, сначала появляется модальное окно, авторизуешься, переходишь ко второму. То  есть нужен обработчик для заполнения логина в первом окне и нажатия кнопки Логин, плюс инициализировать Curl заново?

Comment: `CURLOPT_USERHTTPAUTH` и `CURLOPT_USERPWD` – это должно пройти за первое "модальное" окно. Со второй авторизацией – может помочь ваши куки из браузера, где вы авторизованы, перенести на сервер, с которого работает CURL и указать файл с куками опцией `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE`.

Comment: спасибо. Я внезапно по болезни выскочил из жизни. Хочу вернуться к задаче,

Comment: в форме используется массив услуг $svc=array("химчистка мягкой мебели", "химчистка матрасов", "химчистка ковров на дому","химчистка ковров на фабрике","уборка помещений","иное"); (Чекбоксы в самой форме), 
согласно требованию api:
§ services - массив кодов выбранных услуг: § furniture - химчистка мягкой мебели § mattress - химчистка матрасов § carpet - химчистка ковров на дому § factory-carpet-cleaning - химчистка ковров на фабрике § cleaning - уборка помещений § other - иное

Пример передачи параметров
services[0]=mattress&services[1]=cleaning&services[2]=factory-carpet-cleaning

Comment: Я потерял нить: как ваш последний комментарий отностится к авторизации запросов?

Comment: с авторизацией разобрались, вопрос о передаче отмеченных полей-чекбоксов. cURL работает только с одноуровневыми массивами. Но мы не можем наперед знать, что отметит пользователь из услуг для дальнейшей передачи, как решить эту проблему?

Comment: > cURL работает только с одноуровневыми массивами

Это не так. `curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array( 'lev1' => array( 'lev2_a' => 'val_a', 'lev2_b' => 'val_b')));`

Comment: и все же, как сделать отправку именно checked values?

Comment: @Тим обновил ответ.

Comment: Нет, вам нужно предпринять личное умственное усилие, провести пробы и проанализровать ошибки.

Comment: спасибо, это хороший совет, без дураков